# Launching Activity causes crash

Tags: android, framebuffer

I'll try to make the best sense of this I can...

This app is written in Android Studio, but not using any XML.  It's all framebuffer.  I know that may seem unusual, but if you are building a game, where all the XML activity overhead is unnecessary, it's good to just skip over that.  The Kilobolt Game Framework Tutorial is the base for this.  Over the years I've modified it quite a bit, to handle some newer things.  But that is the core code base.

So, this game works perfectly.  No problems at all.  I recently implemented a live high score table.  That part works great too.

But then I needed to add a method for users to submit their score.  The one thing the framework doesn't allow for is text entry.  Like, not even at all.  My solution to this was to add an XML activity.  It is only used for submitting the score.  So other than that, it is not even part of the program.

This works great on my LG phone (Android 7.0).  Works great in the emulator (Android 7.0).
But as soon as I try to launch the activity on an older device (Android 6.0 and older), the program crashes.

This is the error log that I get from Google Play:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:1420)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity (ContextImpl.java:1407)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity (ContextWrapper.java:323)
  at com.klawton.twentyonegameads.showScores.launchScores (showScores.java:297)
  at com.klawton.twentyonegameads.showScores.update (showScores.java:192)
  at com.klawton.framework.implementation.AndroidFastRenderView.run (AndroidFastRenderView.java:47)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
```

Tracing this down, you can see the parts that are my programs.  showScores.launchScores is the void that invokes the Intent to start the activity. At that point, showScores should be in the background and the new Activity on top.  Like I said, this works as intended on newer systems.   The line in AndroidFastRenderView is the call from the main app to run the update() void on the current screen, which is currently in the background.  That appears to be where the app crashes.

I tried putting that in a try/catch.  That just makes the activity fail to launch.  I tried telling the main program to pause.  It still crashes.  I tried setting a boolean to disable the update with the Activity is open.  Still the app crashes.

If anyone has any ideas on what is happening here, that would be great.

EDIT:
Here is the entire code for the Context .java.

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
I hooked up my old phone and got a reasonable error message:

```
E/MYAPP: exception: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Comment: What's in lines `ContextImpl:1420` and `1407` and `ContextWrapper:223` for that SDK?

Comment: I have never once looked that deep into the provided SDK code.  I don't even know where to find that.  Considering it seems to appear before the other stuff, I ignored it.

Comment: As a stop-gap for now, I'm changing my compileSDKVersion to 24 (it was 23).  I'll post back if that seems to help.

Comment: Also - that stack trace does not have the complete error message (these are removed for privacy reasons in the Google Developer Console). Maybe you can try and reproduce on your emulator/real phone or install Crashlytics to get the full message

Comment: That sort of thing was a lot easier in older versions.  I don't even know how to get a stack trace off of an older device anymore.  I suppose it's time to find a program for it.

Comment: What `Context` instance are you calling `startActivity` on?

Comment: I've added the entire .java for how the context is grabbed.

Comment: Update:  That bit with the flag.  That fixed the problem.  The new activity launches without crashing.